# Spherical harmonics: how's Laplace's equation related to spheres?

Tags: special-functions, harmonic-functions, spherical-harmonics

Many spherical harmonics derivations start from finding a solution to Laplace's equation and the results are in fact what are called spherical harmonics.

However, how's Laplace's equation really related to spheres?

Particularly, Wikipedia says spherical harmonics being defined "on the surface of a sphere".

Comment: They turn up when you use spherical coordinates in solving the associated PDE.